# How does import main from another file

Tags: python

I have 2 files: project/pipline.py and project/partA/algorithm.py.

On algorithm.py file I have main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument('--a', type=str)
     parser.add_argument('--b', type=str)
     parser.add_argument('--c', type=str)
```

I want call this function from the pipline script,

I tried:

```
from partA.algorithm import main
main()
```

but it doesn't work.
How can I do that, and how can I send argument?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this in your algorithm.py file:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--a', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--b', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--c', type=str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The line `if __name__ == '__main__':` just checks that the python file isn't being run as an imported module, and if so, runs the code inside the block. It doesn't define a function which can be imported.

Comment: There is any option without change algorithm.py file, only pipline.py?

Comment: You can only import functions or variables, you can't import if statements. You could just manually write the code from algorithm.py into pipeline.py?

Comment: ok thanks, and how do I send the arguments to the algorithm.py file?

Comment: What arguments? You don't have any arguments in `pipeline.py`

Comment: algorithm.py need to get a, b, c arguments, I want to run `python pipline.py --a '1 '--b '2' --c '3'` command